# How to fix "py:872: axes.color_cycle is deprecated and replaced with axes.prop_cycle;"?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am totally brand new to programming and attempting to learn Python. So, please bear with me during the phase of asking dump questions. The error above is what I got when I attempted to import matplotlib.pyplot into Python. I'm not sure of how to resolve this so I hope somebody can help me. Thanks!

Comment: You are probably using an outdated scripts/module. Update if possible, if error is still there, trace down where axes.color_cycle is used, and manually replace it with prop_cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Open your `matplotlibrc` file and search for `axes.color_cycle`. If you're getting the error message it means that your `matplotlibrc` file should show something like this:

```
axes.color_cycle : b, g, r, c, m, y, k  # color cycle for plot lines
```

You should replace that line by this:

```
axes.prop_cycle : cycler('color', ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k'])
```

And the error message should be gone.